# Unable to create Databases in Azure SQL Managed SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

When running the create DB from the managed instance I get this message.

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "LinkedInvalidPropertyId",
        "message": "Property id '' at path 'properties.recoverableDatabaseId' is invalid. Expect fully qualified resource Id that start with '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'."
    }
}
```

I tried creating the database from SSMS and got the same type of error messages.

Comment: You're not alone,  receiving the exact same error message on 2/13/23.  I attempted to perform a restore from an on prem database .bak several times which failed then I tired creating a blank database and it didn't work either.

Comment: It's two days later (2/15/23),  everything is now working fine, restore and creating a blank database both work as expected.

Comment: Sweet I will try it now myself.

Comment: Huzzah mine works too... wonder what Microsoft Borked up this time?